# uiscrollview programmatically in autolayout

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios7, uiscrollview, autolayout

[image]

I am new to auto layout concept. I am adding a scroll view programmatically, it works in iOS 8 but in iOS 7 scroll view is not working, can any one help me how I can get this to work?

```
UIScrollView *scroll = [[UIScrollView alloc]init];
[scroll setTranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints:NO];
scroll.contentSize=CGSizeMake(480, 700+100);

[contactview addSubview:scroll];

NSDictionary *scrolldic = @{@"scrollview":scroll};
NSArray *scroll_H = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"H:[scrollview(480)]" options:0 metrics:Nil views:scrolldic];

NSArray *scroll_V = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"V:[scrollview(568)]" options:0 metrics:Nil views:scrolldic];

[scroll addConstraints:scroll_H];
[scroll addConstraints:scroll_V];

NSArray *scroll_posH = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"H:|-0-[scrollview]" options:0 metrics:Nil views:scrolldic];

NSArray *scroll_posV = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"V:|-140-[scrollview]" options:0 metrics:Nil views:scrolldic];

[self.view addConstraints:scroll_posH];
[self.view addConstraints:scroll_posV];
```

Is this the correct way to set scroll view?

[image]

Comment: Why don't you use the interface builder?

Comment: i want in programmatically only.

Comment: what are you trying to achieve? shall the scrollview take up the whole screen? or just a portion? what is inside that scrollview?

Comment: @AndreSlotta scroll view takes only half, inside that i am having text field , labels

Comment: and do you mean by half? half of the width? half of the height?

Comment: btw you add `scroll` as a subview of `contactview` but later you add constraints to `self.view`. i don't think that is what you want, is it?

Comment: width = 320 , height is end of the screen

Comment: i am just new to this can u help me in your coding

Comment: can you maybe upload a picture or something of how you want that layout to be? cause i do not understand that yet. you talk about a width of 320 but i do not see that magic number in your code anywhere...

Comment: wait 1 min i will uplode

Comment: i have up lode the image , in side the black image, scroll view should appear, u got it

Comment: ok. so if i understand correctly you want your scrollview to pin the left, right and bottom edges to the screen edges. and the top edge below the "days, hours, minutes..." view. right?

Comment: oh wait. the contactview is the black view? and you want the scrollview to be inside that view?

Comment: hole view is contactview i added one image inside the contactview , inside that black image scroll should appear

Comment: then why don't you add scroll as a subview of that imageview?

Comment: i have added but in ios 7 scroll view not working

Comment: wanna share your project? then i could take a look...

Comment: in my company its not allowed

Comment: ok, i understand... but then it's kinda hard to help you... if you add the scrollview as a subview to that imageview the only two lines of constraints to add **to the imageview** are those: `H:|[scrollview]|` and `V:|[scrollView]|` - and of course take care of the scrollviews contentsize. btw: you do not have to set the contentsize directly if you also use autolayout for the scrollviews subviews!